# How to remove blue background of icon on a desktop?

Tags: c#, uwp

The problem is this

[image]

How do i remove blue background of icon?

I use asset generator in Package.appxmanifest file

[image]

And that is what I get:

[image]

But background is blue on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a desktop shortcut, system uses the current system accent color behind the `png` you have provided. Actually, when the user's color theme changes, the icon will still keep the accent color from the time it was created.  Unfortunately, you can't avoid this behavior currently except using a solid color background behind the icon. So it is a limitation caused by the fact that UWP apps were tiles-first and only now it is starting to be possible to create shortcuts on desktop.

However, if you provide `unplated` icon assets, those will be used when the app is pinned to the task bar at least.